# range based for loop for custom linked list containing pointers in C++, only returns objects

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, range, containers

We wrote a custom container class that should be able to support rang based for loop, see here: [c++ shell](http://cpp.sh/5wubk). When you run the example you can see that it is working.

Essentially the container is a *linked list of pointers to Elements*:

```
    LinkedList ll;
    ll.push_back(new Element(1));
    ll.push_back(new Element(2));
    ll.push_back(new Element(3));

    for(LinkedList::iterator it = ll.begin(); it != ll.end(); ++it){
        cout << it->some_value << endl;
    }

    for(Element ele : ll) {
        cout << ele.some_value << endl;
    }
```

will print`123123`. What we don't understand is: Why are the `ele` in the range based for loop not pointers? Or better why does this not work:

```
for(Element * ele : ll) {
    cout << ele->some_value << endl;
}
```

Basically we want to achieve the same with the custom linked list as can be achieved with the std vector:

```
vector<Element*> vec{new Element(1),new Element(2),new Element(3)};
for(Element * ele : vec)
{
    cout<<ele->some_value<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Look at what `LinkedList::begin()` and `LinkedList::end()` return. Range based for loops will dereference those iterators for you. Note that each `ele` is a *copy* of the elements in `ll`. Use a reference to avoid that copy. To support your suggestion, you would need to be able to convert `Element&` to `Element *` implicitly.

Comment: Because `Element ele` is not a pointer?

Comment: I'm guessing you want `for (const auto& ele : ...` like one usually does...

Comment: No, what we really want is `for(Element * ele : vec)`. I mean it is possible with the std vector, it should be possible with our custom linked list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard defines the ranged based for to be equivalent to:

```
{
  auto && __range = range-init;
  for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
             __end = end-expr;
        __begin != __end;
        ++__begin )
  {
    for-range-declaration = *__begin;
    statement
  }
}
```

The reason `ele` shouldn't be a pointer is because of the dereference of the iterator (`for-range-declaration = *__begin;`), so the for-range-declaration needs to be a reference type or the actual value type.

Hence you need to change your iterator class such that the operator* returns `Element*` or `Element*&`.

Comment: That is kind of a bit too abstract... what do we have to change such that `for(Element * ele : ll)` is working?

Comment: @newandlost: You need to change your iterator class such that `operator*` returns `Element*` or `Element*&`.

Comment: The way in which the anser is written like `for-range-declaration = *__begin;` is that c++ documentation language?